# Postgresql cant change max_connections

Tags: database, postgresql, config

Here I have an issue. At this moment, I am using postgresql 10. I cant change default value of the `max_connections = 100`. I have tried to edit config `postgresql.conf`, tried to do this with sql query `ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections TO 'num';`. After any changes, I tried to restart postgresql `sudo service postgresql restart`. But `SHOW max_connections` sql query still outputs with: `max_connections = 100`. 
How to change max_connections value???

Comment: Sounds like the restart is failing, or restarting the wrong server. 
 Instead of restart, shut it down.  Verify you can't connect.  Start it up again.

Comment: @jjanes I did it. But this still don't work. Well, I stopped the service and started postgres manually with -N param (max_connections). And it works now by this way.